# Solving recurrenc using recurrence tree method.

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I got this recurrence to solve: $T(n) = 2.1 T(n/2) + n$.

I know the answer (got it using the plug and chug method and using the master method too), but I'm trying to solve using recurrence tree and the result doesn't match.

The problem that I'm having is how to deal with this $a$ that multiplies $T(2/n$). Anybody can give me a clue how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It would help us if you gave more context to your question, as well as details about what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you. Right now i'm trying to construct the recurrence tree. Think i just found the solution. I was bulding the recurrence tree wrong. Know i have the following tree(sorry not using the styled text on the answer, but soon as possible i'm gonna right this down correctly) so, i got this tree:

Comment: level 1: `n`
level 2: `(n/2) 0,9(n/2)`
level 3: `(n/4) 0,9(n/4) 0,9(n/4) 0,9^2(n/4)`
level 4: `(n/8) 0,9(n/8) 0,9(n/8) 0,9^2(n/8) 0,9(n/8) 0,9^2(n/8) 0,9^2(n/8) 0,9^3(n/8)`

Doing this i got the same answer as using other methods like plug and chug for the sum for done by each level.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
 $$\frac{T(n)}n=\frac{T(\frac n2)}{\frac n2}+1$$

Put $\frac{T(n)}n=F(n), F(n)=F(\frac n2)+1$

If $n=2^m, F(2^m)=F(2^r)+m-r=F(2^0)+m$

Comment: Great answer, now answer this: what is a recurrence tree, and the master method?

Comment: @vadim123, this can help: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html

Comment: lab bhattacharjee, thank you for your solution. I haven't got yet how the "substitution" could help me out with the 2.1 that multiplies the T(n/2). I got one solution here drawing the recurrence tree right, soon as possible i'm gonna past here. Thank you again.